# Would this design be considered accessible?

Tags: accessibility

I'm currently working on an app directed towards people with physical disabilities, and I have been trying to follow the guidelines of material design for accessible apps.

The problem comes with this lateral scroll, which for now is just a proof of concept but it's made to see if people with disabilities understand that you can scroll there and if they have he dexterity to purposefully scroll it.

Here is a video of me scrolling it:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has noticeable problems, starting with the contrast ratio and a lack of indicators about the behavior of the element (for example: arrows, dots, a label, etc.).

A more comprehensive answer depends on whether you're targeting specific disabilities or full accessibility, and of course user testing. It's not the same to make a site accessible for the visually impaired and for motor disabilities, and we don't know what [**level of accessibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html#uc-levels-head) you're aiming for. In Spain the minimum is AA (I see the app is for Murcia), but for an app about accessibility I'd expect full AAA or at least 80%.

I don't know if you have a plan about accessibility scores you need to reach. If not, I suggest you start with that, and maybe run some automatic testing using tools like [WebAIM](https://wave.webaim.org/) (it has the **WAVE** tool for desktop, which is pretty good, but you'll need to convert your app to desktop). This being said, automatic accessibility tools are just a guidance, there's no way to cover all a11y issues automatically.

Comment: With the contrast ratio you mean the colors of the icons on the background as I understand. On release those would've been understandable images, I just wanted to check the movement itself. And thanks a LOT for the W3C accessibility guidelines, I thought those were just for web devs. I have now more rules to apply to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You've already received a thorough answer but I've had this question in my mind as it relates to my own design work: is a horizontal scroll almost always going to be deemed inaccessible?

My thought process: does the fact that a phone screen is much less wide than it is tall inhibit the user from making detailed gestures in any way? Physical disabilities can take many forms but for users who may have a hard time making a controlled gesture in a small space I could see this being an issue.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to UX StackExchange. Please use the answer section for answering questions; you are welcome to post a new question if you have one (others might have the same question as well). The format here is Q&A vs. open dialog. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies - there is a question in there. I've rephrased my response.